# Inverse of a function in wolfram alpha

Tags: roots, inverse, wolfram-alpha, inverse-function

I tried to look up the inverse of the function in the picture, but I don't understand what wolfram alpha gives me as an answer, can someone help me?

[link to picture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aa36p.jpg)

Comment: Mathematica can't solve the equation $$y=\frac{4x^5}{1+x^2}$$ in explicit form

Comment: Alright thanks, are there any methods to find the inverse of such a complex function?

Comment: It's also possible to obtain the power series for the inverse (near a given point), or to obtain approximations for the inverse as $y \to \pm \infty$.